# Android : Populate a spinner list with async task in a loop

Tags: android, asynchronous

I have problems with populating a spinner list with multiple Async Task to retrieve data.

The first question is to put show the progress dialog and hide it ? (Problem with multiple async task)

And is it correct to create and set new adapter every time ?

Here is my code

```
public void getEntities(Entity account) {

    final ArrayList <Entity> entities = new ArrayList <Entity>();

    Log.i(TAG, String.valueOf(account.getRelationships().size()));

    for(final Relationship relationship : account.getRelationships()) {

        new SOAPCall() {
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String soapResponse) {
                final DataMap dm = ParseSoapResponse.parseEntity(soapResponse);
                Entity ent = new Entity(dm.getDataMapArrayList("items").get(0).getString("displayName"));
                ent.setLogicalName(relationship.getReferenceEntity());

                entities.add(ent);

                spinnerAdapterEntities = new ArrayAdapter <Entity> (getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, entities);
                spinnerAdapterEntities.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                _spinner_entities1.setAdapter(spinnerAdapterEntities);

            }
        }.execute(SoapRequest.getInstance(getBaseContext()).getRetrieveEntityRequest(relationship.getReferenceEntity(), "Entity"));


    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AsyncTasks are quite inefficient, so I would suggest using only one AsyncTask. That would solve all your current problems. You would show progress in onPreExecute, loop trough Relationships in doInBackground, update your adapter in onProgressUpdate and hide progress in onPostExecute.

Comment: So I should pass all my SOAP Request (e.g. in a list) to my SOAPCall class and execute them in one Async Task ?

Comment: @bidou88 yes, AsyncTask's `execute` method takes a list (or array or single or none) of parameters, which can be a Relationship objects.

Answer (score 1):

Override your AsyncTask class with `onPreExecute()` and `onPostExecute()` methods.

Example :

```
private class DoSomething extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    ProgressDialog pd;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        pd = ProgressDialog.show(context, null, "Loading...");
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Do something here...
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        pd.dismiss();
    }
}
```

With a simple hack in your case, since it is a multiple AsyncTask, init your ProgressDialog in your `SOAPCall` constructor, and in `onPostExecute()` of every AsyncTask, check if `ProgressDialog` is null. If is not null, then call `ProgressDialog.dismiss()`, else, do nothing.

You do not set a new ADAPTER every time, it is hard to control the data source (ArrayList). Make a custom Spinner adapter, implement your own ArrayList update method, then call `SpinnerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` when you update your array list.

P.S : It is a very bad practice, hence, do stick to ONE AsyncTask only.